# Trouble in understanding a line of code in c

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I am working on an exercise where this is a piece of the code:

```
typedef struct node 
{
    size_t size;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

byte heap[SIZE];

node_t *node_list;

void heap_init()
{
    node_list = (node_t*) heap;
    node_list->size = SIZE;
    node_list->next = NULL;
}
```

But i have some trouble under standing the line:

```
node_list = (node_t*) heap;
```

Comment: Offtopic: peace ->piece.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour as `heap` may not be correctly aligned for `node_t`. Also it violates the strict aliasing rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`heap` is an array of bytes of size `SIZE`.

`node_list` is a pointer of type `node_t`. This pointer is assigned to the first byte of the array `heap`. What this does is that `node_list` is assigned to an allocated location of memory.

I am guessing that the next pointer for the list will be assigned to a location further along this array.

This is most probably simulating a heap in the global variables, and avoids the use of `malloc` which cannot be used some embedded systems.

Answer (score 1):

The code is using the memory allocated for `heap` to store a `node_t` instance in, rather that allocate it using one of the `malloc` school of functions functions.

The variable `heap` on its own degraded to a pointer to `byte*` and the code says "I want to reinterpret the `byte*` as a `node_t*` pointer".

Note that for this to work the value `SIZE` must be at least `sizeof(node_t)`, otherwise the `node_t` instance won't fit within the `heap` variable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the code you are pointing to is using a **less common method** of **allocating memory** i.e. as **byte array**..
instead of a common method of malloc or calloc

**Now**

**node_list = (node_t*) heap;**

All one can infer from this line is 
since **heap** is a byte array here, and

**node_list** which is a **pointer** to **struct node** type is pointing to the **starting address** of your **byte array** named **heap** and since the pointer would be **byte* type** it is typecasted to **struct node*** type.

One can infer it just like
struct node * ptr = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

here (struct node*) is used in front of malloc(sizeof(struct node)); to typecast **void** type of pointer returned by malloc to match the required **struct node** type on left side of '=' equal sign.

hope it helps :)